# Lightning Experience App Manager - Tabs customization

Tags: lightning-app-manager

I currently hold SalesForce System Admin privileges in in our organization, and I was looking into adding new tabs (& deleting some) in the "Sales" App which is still in Classic mode. If I were to Update the app type from Classic to Lightning, would that affect all other users in my organization or solely my ID?

Thank you,

Lidia B.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would affect all users. Generally speaking, anything you do in Setup affects all users, while anything you do in Personal Settings only affects yourself. For example, you could customize the tabs that are displayed out of all available tabs in an app, and that would only affect your account.

Comment: Thank you, that helps!